# Is there an equivalent/replacement of ANY_VALUE (of SQL) in Apache Pinot Query

Tags: apache-pinot, pinot

I'm looking for a function in Apache Pinot that can replace ANY_VALUE from SQL.
My query in SQL is

```
SELECT
 id, 
 ANY_VALUE(kind) AS kind
 ...
GROUP BY id
```

The closest function I find in Pinot is `FIRSTWITHTIME`

```
SELECT
 id, 
 FIRSTWITHTIME(kind, date, 'STRING') as NAME_DIFF_KIND
 ...
GROUP BY id
```

Disadv: it cannot remain the same name as current column.

Is there any function can do this?